# rolling apply in pandas shows "TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars"

Tags: python, arrays, function, pandas, median

Dataframe `df_implied_full` has several columns, one of them is called `'USDZARV1Y Curncy'`, and it has only `floats`.

This code works:

```
mad                          = lambda x: np.median(np.fabs(x - np.median(x)))
df_implied_full['madtest']   = df_implied_full['USDZARV1Y Curncy'].rolling(window=60).apply(mad)
```

This code doesn't work:

```
test                         = lambda x: (x - np.median(x))
df_implied_full['rolltest2'] = df_implied_full['USDZARV1Y Curncy'].rolling(window=60).apply(test)
```

The error shown is:

> File "pandas\algos.pyx", line 1831, in pandas.algos.roll_generic (pandas\algos.c:51581)
>
> TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

I'm using Pandas 0.18.1 and python 2.7.12

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: `x` is a Series of lenght 60. `x - np.median(x)` is also a series of the same shape because it is broadcasted. The one above, with `np.median(...)`, is a scalar so it works because for each 60 period window you need a scalar returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem output of `x` in `lambda x: (x ...` is `numpy array`, so if use only `test = lambda x: x` numpy array cannot be converted to scalar values per each row. I think you need return scalar value only e.g. use `x[0]` or `np.median(x)`. The best is use custom function and test it.

Sample with `window=2`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_implied_full = pd.DataFrame({'USDZARV1Y Curncy': [1.2,4.6,7.3,4.9,1.5]})
print (df_implied_full)

def test (x):
    print (x)

    #[ 1.2  4.6]
    #[ 4.6  7.3]
    #[ 7.3  4.9]
    #[ 4.9  1.5]

    print (type(x))
    #<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
    #<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
    #<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
    #<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

    #Return only first value of list
    return x[0]

mad                          = lambda x: np.median(np.fabs(x - np.median(x)))
df_implied_full['madtest']   = df_implied_full['USDZARV1Y Curncy'].rolling(window=2).apply(test)

print (df_implied_full)
   USDZARV1Y Curncy  madtest
0               1.2      NaN
1               4.6      1.2
2               7.3      4.6
3               4.9      7.3
4               1.5      4.9
```

---

```
def test (x):
def test (x):
    print (x)

    #[ 1.2  4.6]
    #[ 4.6  7.3]
    #[ 7.3  4.9]
    #[ 4.9  1.5]

    #Return median as scalar
    return np.median(x)

mad                          = lambda x: np.median(np.fabs(x - np.median(x)))
df_implied_full['madtest']   = df_implied_full['USDZARV1Y Curncy'].rolling(window=2).apply(test)

print (df_implied_full)
   USDZARV1Y Curncy  madtest
0               1.2      NaN
1               4.6     2.90
2               7.3     5.95
3               4.9     6.10
4               1.5     3.20
```

Comment: "I think you need return scalar value only" this phrase is what gave me the answer. thanks  @jezrael